# Angular Upgraded App - SharedModule Components not rendering and/or erroring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, systemjs

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/itsphil/a1bfed03ed81071161c37ee3b676208b)

We have an application that is running with the Angular `UpgradeModule`. We have a strictly angular(2) feature module that is trying to make use of a SharedModule Component. It is producing either errors or not rendering the component.

I have followed the Angular guides on this, including [this guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#a-trimmer-_appmodule_) to no avail. I have attached the Gist of our setup at the top of this post for you to review.

If I include the `UIModule` in the `FeatureModule` I get no errors but the component `ui-dropdown` does not render the template.

If I do not include `UIModule` in the `FeatureModule`, I get console errors as per the below;

[image: run time error]

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a custom schema in your module, like the error suggests? :) -> `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`

Comment: @AJT_82 yes, has no effect

Comment: In feature.module.ts, it looks like import statement should be like- import { UIModule } from "app/ui/shared.module";

Comment: @user6801750 that was a typo, apologies.